# Inputs in reactjs form filling at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Hello there so basically my problem is that the inputs on my form are being filled at the same time. When I write something on the first name input it is written in the last name, email and phone input at the same time but I want them to work separately. I think it might be a problem with the handleChange I've been trying different ways but none of them works

here is my code:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleChangeFname = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeLname = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePhone = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      value: null
    };
  }

  getValidationStateFname() {
    const fname = this.state.value;
    if (this.state.value === null) return null;
    else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(fname)) return 'error';
    else if (/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(fname)) return 'success';
  }
  getValidationStateLname() {
    const lname = this.state.value;
    if (this.state.value === null) return null;
    else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(lname)) return 'error';
    else if (/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(lname)) return 'success';
  }
  getValidationStateEmail() {
    const email = this.state.value;
    if (this.state.value === null) return null;
    else if (!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) return 'error';
    else if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) return 'success';
  }
  getValidationStatePhone() {
    const phone = this.state.value;
    if (this.state.value === null) return null;
    else if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(phone)) return 'error';
    else if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(phone)) return 'success';
  }

  handleChange(fname) {
    this.setState({ value: fname.target.value });
  }

  handleChange(lname) {
    this.setState({ value: lname.target.value });
  }

  handleChange(email) {
    this.setState({ value: email.target.value });
  }

  handleChange(phone) {
    this.setState({ value: phone.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
      <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
          <Col sm={9} md={6}>
          <FormGroup
            controlId="formBasicText"
            validationState={this.getValidationStateFname()}
            >
            <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="First Name"
            onChange={this.handleChangeFname}
            />
            <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={9} md={6}>
          <FormGroup
          controlId="formBasicText"
          validationState={this.getValidationStateLname()}
          >
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="Last Name"
            onChange={this.handleChangeLname}
          />
          <FormControl.Feedback />
          </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={9} md={6}>
          <FormGroup
          controlId="formBasicText"
          validationState={this.getValidationStateEmail()}
          >
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="E-mail"
            onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
          />
          <FormControl.Feedback />
          </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={9} md={6}>
          <FormGroup
          controlId="formBasicText"
          validationState={this.getValidationStatePhone()}
          >
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            onChange={this.handleChangePhone}
          />
          <FormControl.Feedback />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
        </Row>
        </Grid>
      </form>

    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: You have 4 methods with the same name, `handleChange`. Name them differently, e.g. `handleEmailChange`, `handlePhoneChange`, ... You also want to have one separate state variable for each input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inputs are changing at the same time because you are keeping just one `value` for all your inputs in the state. First keep different inputs for each one:

```
this.state = {
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
};
```

Then, give a `name` to each your `FormControl`:

```
<FormControl
    type="text"
    name="fname"
    value={this.state.fname}
    placeholder="First Name"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Here, change also `value` to `this.state.fname` (name the other ones according to this) and `onChange` to `handleChange`. We are writing one `handleChange` method for all the inputs. Here:

```
handleChange = ( event ) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   this.setState({ [name]: value });
}
```